# Zend Framework 1.12 can't add stylesheets from view templates

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a layout which include a template called "_slider.phtml". Inside the "_slider.phtml" template I am trying toinclude a stylesheet using headLink() but for some reason its not showing up. I also don't get any errors. Even if I place the code in "_top.html" or the layout itself same thing happens. The headScript() works fine but headLink() doesn't.

I have the following layout structure.

```
<html>
<head>
<?php echo $this->headMeta(); ?>
<?php echo $this->headLink(); ?>
<?php echo $this->headStyle(); ?>
</head>
<body class="body">

    <?php echo $this->render('_top.phtml'); ?>

    <?php echo $this->render('_slider.phtml', 'slider'); ?>

    <?php echo $this->headScript(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is my "_slider.phtml" template.

```
<?php $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet($this->baseUrl('/template/select.css?ver=3.0.1')); ?> //Doesn't work...

<h2>Hello World...</h2>
```

Can anyone please explain why this is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the point that `$this->render('_slider.phtml', 'slider');`  is called 
headLink(); ?> has already occured.

The only real options here is to call `<?php echo $this->render('_slider.phtml', 'slider'); ?>` prior to the headLink call.

You can do this by reordering your code like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<?php $slider = $this->render('_slider.phtml', 'slider'); ?>
<?php echo $this->headMeta(); ?>
<?php echo $this->headLink(); ?>
<?php echo $this->headStyle(); ?>
</head>
<body class="body">
    <?php echo $this->render('_top.phtml'); ?>
    <?php echo $slider; ?>
    <?php echo $this->headScript(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```